# Custom column into custom taxonomy (img tag with slug-name as file name)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, columns

How to add $term->name (slug) into custom column cells as the file name?

```
$columns = '<img src="SLUG_NAME.jpg">';



function custom_column_header( $columns ){
        $columns['image'] = 'Image';
        return $columns;
    }
    add_filter( "manage_edit-genre_columns", 'custom_column_header', 10);

    function custom_column_content( $value, $column_name, $term_id ){
        if ($column_name === 'image') {
            $columns = '<img src="SLUG_NAME.jpg">';
        }
        return $columns;
    }
    add_action( "manage_genre_custom_column", 'custom_column_content', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/) like this:

```
if ($column_name === 'image') {
    $slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $term_id );
    $columns = '<img src="' . $slug . '.jpg">';
}
```

Or [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/):

```
if ($column_name === 'image') {
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    $columns = '<img src="' . $term->slug . '.jpg">';
}
```